# How to set the working directory when running an executable in Eclipse CDT to be the same as the executable?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have several build dirs for different configurations (using an external build system from the CLI), so the executable name duplicates the desired cwd:

- `path/to/build1/executable`
- `path/to/build1` (desired cwd)
- `path/to/build2/executable`
- `path/to/build2` (desired cwd)

Is there a more convenient way to run the executable from the directory containing it, without typing the path twice?

The most likely solution would be with a variable like `${workspace_loc}` under "Arguments -> Working directory", but I could not find a suitable variable.

Tested on Eclipse 4.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

If you use managed build you can get away with specifying config_name appended to workspace_loc, i.e. if you project is called "test" this should work (tested on linux)

${workspace_loc:test}/${config_name:test}

My app prints
Current working dir: /home/elaskavaia/workspace/test/Debug