# How to set the current working directory of the program when remote debugging with gdbserver Automatic Launcher in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I tried to change it with Debug configurations > Arguments > Working directory, but that only changes the location of the host gdb.

This can be observed by either:

- creating a test program that prints `pwd`
- `pwdx` on the process
- `pwd` on the Eclipse Debugger Console

When using CLI `gdb` and `gdbserver`, we observe that the `pwd` of the program is always the same as where `gdbserver` was launched, and the `pwd` and `cd` commands on host only change host settings.

The Automatic Launcher SSHs into the target and launches `gdbserver` for us, which automates the re-run process: [Remote debugging C++ applications with Eclipse CDT/RSE/RDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685104/remote-debugging-c-applications-with-eclipse-cdt-rse-rdt/45658783#45658783)

Eclipse 4.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

The best method I could find was to go:

- Debug configurations
- Main
- Commands to execute before application
- `cd /directory/that/I/want`

If you want to set it to the same directory as the executable without duplication, this unsolved question is related: [How to set the working directory when running an executable in Eclipse CDT to be the same as the executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093936/how-to-set-the-working-directory-when-running-an-executable-in-eclipse-cdt-to-be)

Alternatively, you could also use the Manual Launcher, in which you launch `gdbserver` manually on the target. Then just `cd` to the directory you want before running it.